# primefaces picklist custom validator validates too soon

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces, picklist

I have a picklist, embedded in a wizard, that should only go on the next step if something is selected in the target. It works, but the problem is that the validation fires on rendering: the first thing the user see, is the error message, even before hitting the "next" button. Is there any way to turn this off?

Here is the xhtml:

```
<p:pickList id="pickList" value="#{someBean.Rules}"
            var="rule"
            itemLabel="#{rule.name}"
            itemValue="#{rule}"
            converter="accountingObjectConverter"
            responsive="true"
            showSourceFilter="true" showTargetFilter="true"
            filterMatchMode="contains"
            style="width: 100%"
            validator="myValidator"
        >

    <f:facet name="sourceCaption">Select</f:facet>
    <f:facet name="targetCaption">Selected</f:facet>

    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{rule.name}"/>
    </p:column>
</p:pickList>
```

Here is my validator:

```
  @FacesValidator("myValidator")
  public class MyValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        checkForEmptyFields(context, component, (DualListModel) value);
    }

    private void checkForEmptyFields(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, DualListModel value) {
        if ( value.getTarget().size() == 0) {
            ((UIInput) component).setValid(false);
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error: must select at least one item", ""));
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time.

*EDIT*: here is the wizzard:

```
<h:form id="mainForm">
    <p:wizard id="ruleWizard" widgetVar="ruleWiz"
              flowListener="#{aBeanL.flowListener}"
              nextLabel="next"
              backLabel="back">

        <p:tab id="queryTab" title="rules">
            <ui:include src="theXhtmlAbove.xhtml"/>
        </p:tab>
        *some tabs*

    </p:wizard>
</h:form>
```

Comment: You talk about a wizard but do not posts its code. Is it not relevant? If it is, please post its code to and make it into an mcve?

Comment: the wizzard's code added, it might be relevant indeed, thank you for your advice!

Comment: If it **is** relevant could/should be tested by you. What if you just use this picklist code directly in a page, no wizard? And what if you don't use an include...